# How do I mathematically model a magnetic levitation system?

Tags: electromagnetism, control, control-system, pid-controller, math

I am working on a magnetic levitation system project using PID control, and I am getting confused as to how I am supposed to mathematically model this system for my paper. Where am I supposed to start? What equations do I use?

I have found some equations from some thesis, but they just show the equation and do not explain how they arrived at such conclusions.

I would really grateful if anyone could provide guidance or even a tutorial on how I get to model a magnetic levitation system, along with how/what I am supposed to do with the system with PID.

The type of system I am working on is this:
[image]

Comment: The Object will have a very low Mutual coupling of the H field leakage. gravity will make it unstable unless an equilibrium force cancels mass with acceleration compensation with something less than inverse squared gap loss

Comment: So seeing that's the case, you would use the a 2nd order equation of motion to first model the non linearity then solve it right? Is there a guide I can read about so that I can properly understand how to apply this to my system? Because whilst I can get this information from a paper, the problem is actually understanding why I have to use them and solve them for my system.

Comment: https://www.slideshare.net/SalimAlOufi/mse6183finalprojectwriteupslso05052015rev2#:~:text=This%20project%20is%20about%20controlling%20the%20position%20of,feedback%20of%20the%20position%20of%20the%20magnetic%20ball.?msclkid=ed73953da6fd11eca322287678e98ddb

Comment: both papers here and in Nedd's answer use dual IR position feedback rather than Hall Sensor

Answer (score 1):

Here's one reference paper with equations: [Optimized PID Controller for Magnetic Levitation System](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405896316301513)

Comment: More of a comment than an answer. But I'll leave it to the mods.

Comment: Where do they get the magnetic constant from? Why is K which is initially equal to L0xo but then equal to some random magnetic constant????